# How do you include a concat call with other criteria in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have a front end with a singular input to search names however my database separated them into 2 fields. What I want to do is run a concat and like statement alone the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)) LIKE '%John Do%' AND permission_id = 1 AND user_status_id = 1;
```

now I've gotten to this:

```
    let name = req.params.name;
    let userId = req.user;
debugger;
    db.user.findAll({
        where: {
            attributes: [db.sequelize.fn('concat', db.Sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', db.Sequelize.col('last_name'), 'full_name'), {
                like: `%${name}%`
            }],
        },
        include : [
            db.client
        ]
    })
```

but can't think where to include the like or the concat

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators

This may help you, see the operators section.

Comment: I actually figured some of it out I think, but I'm still getting an error. For example when I put in "kyle" it says user not found, though there is a kyle t in the db.

Comment: You can't apply where conditions on a column that is not present in the table. In your case the full name column is generated by you. You should query instead in the first_name column and last_name column separately with OR condition.

Comment: the problem I run into with that though is "kyle t" isn't like "kyle" or "tranel"

Comment: @HariramanRadhakrishnan would you mind terribly explaining a bit more?

Comment: I think the way you're trying is correct. I tried the following versions in my DB.

select * from users where concat(first_name,' ', last_name) like `%eam%`;

select * from users where concat(first_name,' ', last_name) like '%eam%';

The first one throws an error, whereas the second one works fine. Can you try changing the ` to '  in your like statement? It should be like '%${name}%'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171349/discussion-between-kyle-t-and-hariraman-radhakrishnan).